# Rationale for size being a member of UDP header

Tags: sockets, udp

What is the rationale for UDP header to contain size of the datagram in it? Wouldn't size of containing IP datagram (after reassembly) determine the size of UDP packet within it?

One thing which comes to mind is that it was done in order to support other protocols than IP as UDP transport, but this doesn't stand scrutiny for two reasons:

1. It's hard to imagine a lower-level protocol where size of it's message can only be determined by upper-level protocol field;
2. And more importantly, UDP is already tightly coupled with IP. It would not run on any other protocols without variations anyways (and as many people notice, should be actually referred to as UDP/IP).

What am I missing here?

Comment: .... that stackoverflow is for programming Q&A, not protocol design questions...

Comment: @Alnitak, I've seen multiple questions on stack overflow regarding rationale for various aspects of behavioir of systems, languages and protocols. This has a strong relation to programming. And, looking at your profile, seems like you of all people should know the answer?